# How comes, that my book states that internal energy is dependent on volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas, gas, volume

Currently I am reading in the 11 edition of Physical Chemistry, Atkins in the chapter 1st law of thermodynamics.

A few pages ago I learned the following:
[image]

Makes sense for now, as far as I know it depends only on the temperature, which can be estimated with the equal distribution theorem. But a few pages further it suddenly says:

[image]

> The internal energy varies with temperature AND volume

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The first statement refers to an ideal gas. The second one does not specify any system. It just says "a system".

Comment: @nasu Ok, but by dependent on volume he means volume change, doesn't he? I only know that the internal energy decreases when volume work is performed. But he writes as if it would depend on the mere state of the volume.

Comment: @iwab No, he means the internal energy depends on the state of the volume. If there are interactions between the microscopic constituents, the internal energy will depend on how far apart they are on average.

Comment: @iwab The energy is a state parameter. It can depend only on the parameters in a given state and not on the change of a parameter. The change is associated with a process between two states. Work and heat are process parameters.

Comment: @iwab And yes, for a system other than ideal gas there is nothing weird about energy depending on the state of the volume. Even you first quotation, after the part in blue, describes the situation of systems that are not an ideal gas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *specific* internal energy of an ideal gas is a function of temperature only. Using standard engineering thermodynamics nomenclature a system (open or closed) has a certain mass (that can vary with time for an open system); U denotes the total internal energy of all the mass in the system and u is the specific internal energy per unit mass.

I first thought in the figure that U and V were total internal energy and total volume since I usually see u and v for specific internal energy and specific volume. Based on comments by @naus and others I now think U and V in the figure are internal energy and volume per unit mass or perhaps per mole.  So, the figure shows that for a real gas the (specific) internal energy is not a function temperature only.

Comment: It reads to me like the book is talking about some given collection of gas molecules, i.e., the particle number is fixed.

Comment: For a given system, the mass does not depend on volume. The energy diagram refers to a system, not to various systems with different masses.

Comment: @naus I see. So U and V in the figure are per unit mass or perhaps per mole? I corrected my answer accordingly.  By the way, in thermodynamics a 'system' has a mass (that can change with time for an open system) and U typically denotes the total internal energy and u the internal energy per unit mass.

Comment: A clearer statement in the book might be "The internal energy of a **certain amount of** perfect gas is independent of the volume it occupies." to prevent misreading as referring to the internal energy of all perfect gases.